# Options Menu in Android Studio

Tags: android-optionsmenu

I know this is a dumb question but can someone lmk why this stupid options_menu isn't showing in my android studio app.

this is my MainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and this is my options_menu xml that is res/menu/options_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="item 1" />

    <item android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:title="item 2" />

    <item android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:title="item 3" >

        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/subitem1"
                android:title="subitem1"/>
            <item android:id="@+id/subitem2"
                android:title="subitem2"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

I just want the options menu to show up lmao